# Stuck on calling a variable

Tags: python, string, jes

I'm new to JES and I'm stuck on this, I'm sure my coding is wrong. If I entered my age as 21 I want the 2 allocated to variable a and 1 allocated to variable b.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
  def makeSound():
    picture=makeEmptySound(10 * 22050)
    number = requestNumber("Enter Your Age:") 
    a = String('number[1]')
    b = String('number[2]')
    setMediaPath("c:\")
    file = getMediaPath(str(a) + str(b) + ".wav")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes into [sequence-types like `str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) are zero-based in Python, so assuming `requestNumber()` returns a [`float`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex), you'll need to convert it to a [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and then you can do:

```
number = requestNumber("Enter Your Age:") 
number_as_string = str(number)
a, b = number_as_string[0], number_as_string[1]
# [...]
file = getMediaPath(a + b + '.wav')
```

Comment: Can't seem to find the appropriate doc page for requestNumber() but it seems to return a float.

Comment: They forced us to use JES in my first semester at uni. I just ran this in the console area. `type(requestNumber("Prompt"))`.

Comment: @PakkuDon: Nice. I've not used [tag:JES] before.